# Which TFT panel types are better than PVA?

Tags: display, tft

I have a [SyncMaster 173p Plus](http://www.flatpanels.dk/nyhed.php?subaction=showfull&id=1141238907) monitor right now which have a PVA panel.

Comparing my current monitor with a Sony CRT, the CRT clearly had a much better picture. So I would like to come closer to correct colours.

Which TFT panels are better than PVA in terms of colour correctness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different [technologies available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFT_LCD), which one is better, PVA (and S-PVA) or IPS (and S-IPS) is debatable, in terms of color gamut, proper curves, etc. Probably specific model is more important than whether you have PVA or IPS. Also, there are issues of viewing angle, "speed" of the display, etc. However:

1. **Any** monitor needs to be calibrated for proper color representation. I suggest getting something like [DataColor Spyder](http://spyder.datacolor.com/) and calibrating your monitors properly. The difference is night and day, even for the better "pro" monitor models.
2. Your eyes adjust, and if you worked with your Sony CRT you perceive its colors as "correct" even when it might not be so. Same thing with proper brightness, etc.

So I suggest getting your monitor calibrated, the calibration software can even show you the color curves so you know exactly how bad or good your monitor's color representation is.